# what is the issue for the below mentioned code?

Tags: java, xpath

Error:

```
no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//span[text()='Download']"}
```

For the below code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, AWTException {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","D:\\Automation\\software backup\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
       // TC-2 Goto Test URL https://www.jquery-az.com/javascript/demo.php?ex=151.1_1
        driver.get("https://smallpdf.com/word-to-pdf");
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        
        //clicking choose file option
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='Choose Files']")).click();
        
        //wait time 4 sec
        Thread.sleep(4000);

        // put the data in clipboard
        StringSelection s=new StringSelection("C:\\Users\\Vivaan\\Downloads\\Shanthala k Resume..pdf");
        
      //Send the Data from Clipboard to Screen
       Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(s, null);
        
    //Perform Paste operation CONTROL V  and ENTER
        
        Robot r=new Robot();
    
        //Paste 
        r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
        r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
        r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
        r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
        
            
        //ENTER
        r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
        r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
        
    Thread.sleep(16000);
    //click on download
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='Download']")).click();

    Thread.sleep(8000);

    //Close the Browser
            driver.close();
}
```

Comment: Could you try to clarify your question? What are you trying to accomplish?
What research have you done so far? What worked and what didn't?

The error sounds like the "Donwload" element just isn't on the page.

Comment: If I try https://smallpdf.com/word-to-pdf to convert word to pdf it takes longer than a minute. So your 16 seconds are too short. No available Download yet I suppose

Comment: when i try to automate the smallpdf.com by converting word document into pdf ,it is automating till converting word doc to pdf after than it is not downloading.Error message lie(console.warn: SearchSettings: "get: No settings file exists, new profile?" (new Error("", "(unknown module)"))
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: Create New Account
https://www.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html).anything issue with selenium code.

Comment: You can [edit] your question: (1) to provide a meaningful title - because people may not read the question if the title is poor; and (2) to move your comments into the body of the question - because those comments are directly relevant to explaining the problem you are having.